# What is the difference between form data and request payload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I send an AJAX Post request and send parameters in queryString in send() method,

Chrome Developer Tool's XHR capture tool shows the parameters under request payload.
and when I use jquery's post function, 
The tool shows parameters under Form Data section.

What is the difference ?

Comment: For future readers follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597052/how-to-retrieve-request-payload

Comment: @revo This was asked in 2012. The one you linked was asked in 2014. And you're pointing this out in 2019 Whatever works!

Comment: I'm not doing anything wrong here. Although the other question is younger, it received much more attention. Hence my vote.

Comment: @revo Ah I get it. No problem. I'll vote as well.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you have not provided enough information how you use the send function, but I assume that you do not set mime type to specify you are sending form data

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

the data sent are in this case encoded as you encode a query string

```
xhr.send("name=foo&value=bar");
```

otherwise it will not be interpreted as form data by Developer Tools.

jquery does majority of work for you in this regard.

**Update:** To answer explicitly what is the difference...

- if a request (typically POST) has `Content-type` header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the body is expected to be in the form of a standard querystring with url-encoded *key*`=`*value* pairs joined by `&`. **Form data** section then shows the key-value parameters (when viewed parsed). This way was much more common in past because it is a default for HTML forms.
- other cases are shown in **Request payload** section (and nowadays parsed for readability as well for common formats like JSON).

Comment: Visitors should note that the `xhr.setRequestHeader()` call should be placed *between* the `xhr.open()` call and the `xhr.send()` call. Otherwise, you will get a DOM Exception error.

Comment: It does not answer the question `What is the difference between form data and request payload?`, just says how to get one or the other.