# Codeigniter show search results in same view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, codeigniter-url

On Search view, I have this form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal col-centered" method="POST"action="Search/search">
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-centered ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Type something" name="title">
        </div>
   </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-centered">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search"name="submit2">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Form action is set to : action="Search/search"

Search-controler and seach function in that controler. All work fine, after submit form I get result,but result show in :

```
 http://localhost/ci/index.php/Search/search
```

My idea is to show result of function search in same view where is form,so after submit form,to get result on Search view.

Tnx

Comment: its better to use ajax for search purposes since it passes its response to the same html page and you can update your html with the returned response

Comment: I will try now that,tnx

Comment: I would use jqery ajax instead of pure ajax. Keep it simple.

Comment: one advise:do not use function name and class name same.if so that function will treat as constructor(`__construct`) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AJAX to get result in same view.

Ref Ex: 
1. [Learning how to use AJAX with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308054/learning-how-to-use-ajax-with-codeigniter)

2. [AJAX Codeigniter Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887095/codeigniter-ajax-example)

Comment: I will try,tnx for link!

Comment: Please do not provide only links in your answer.Write some details from the link and refer the links as for more details.

Answer (score 0):

in your form(`action="Search/search"`) you set controller `Search` and calling function `search`. In this case when your function execute it will return data from your `search` function.

So your URL looks like  `http://localhost/ci/index.php/Search/search`

If you want remove second search word from URL, you can pass data to `index` of `Search` Controller. So this will solved. then it looks like `http://localhost/ci/index.php/Search`.